# Deep link into app (specific activity) by NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter, deep-linking, ndef

I'm developing an Android app that needs a deep link with an NFC tag.

Here you can see my intent filter for the activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.schedule.ScheduleActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".ui.home.HomeActivity">

    <intent-filter android:label="testDeepLink">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="www.testdeeplink.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/schedule"/>

    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Now when I start this command in adb the application starts with the correct activity (ScheduleActivity):

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.testdeeplink.com/schedule?stop_id=1" com.exmemple.android
```

But when I encode the URL on an NFC tag, scanning that tag just starts the web browser of my phone. What am I missing to start the activity with the NFC tag?

URL encoded on the tag: "http://www.testdeeplink.com/schedule?stop_id=1"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing to put an NFC intent filter in your manifest. URLs on NFC tags won't trigger an intent action VIEW. Instead, they will be sent to activities with the intent action NDEF_DISCOVERED. Consequently, you can receive such an NFC intent by putting an additional intent filter for action NDEF_DISCOVERED in your manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.schedule.ScheduleActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".ui.home.HomeActivity">

    <intent-filter android:label="testDeepLink">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        ...
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="testDeepLinkNFC">
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.testdeeplink.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/schedule" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Note that there seem to be some (unconfirmed?) issues with some devices running Android 6.0+ where the browser seems to hijack URLs from NFC tags despite correct NDEF intent filters. I did not experience this myself so far so I could not further investigate this though.

Comment: Thanks, your solution work but to be sure that the browser doesn't hijack the intent i have used a specific url instead, something like :  "testdeeplink://schedule?stop_id=1"
And now it's working

Comment: @Sagonnicolas Yeah, using your own scheme will certainly prevent the link from being processed by the browser. An alternative would be to add an Android Application Record (AAR) for your app *after your URL record* on the tag. This will also make a device open your app lising in play store if the app is not installed on the device.

Comment: @MichaelRoland May I ask if you have some details about this hijacking issue? It happens to me on Android 10 and I cannot find any workaround (my cards are already issued with type 03/04 (http/https) URL inside NDEF data). Thank you